# iOS 11 Logo and title in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

I have been searching and trying for days but since it's a new thing there's not much information available (or I can't find them).

Anyway, I am trying to get use of new NavBar features in `iOS 11` but I want to put both a logo and a large title (of each `ViewController`) in my `NavBar`. Something like the screenshot below:

[image]

How is it possible to implement this?

**Side Hint:**

For same `app` in `iOS 10` I set the logo to show instead of `titleView` in `NavBar` but now in newer version we want to add the Title too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your code sample it's hard to say what goes wrong for you, but this just works:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        title = "Your title"
    }

    let titleImageView = NavigationImageView()
    titleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")
    navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView
}
```

**EDIT**: To set custom size for your title view you can subclass your `UIView` (UIImageView) and override `sizeThatFits`

```
class NavigationImageView: UIImageView {
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works but now I have another problem, the size of logo is so big even though I have set the size `titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 64, height: 30)` this part of code works fine with `iOS 10` but in `iOS 11` it doesn't work, is it changed in new `iOS`?

Comment: Thanks it's what I needed, I have another question about Nav and iOS 11 :D may I ask?

Comment: Go ahead, I'll answer if I know :)

Comment: thanks :) Since it was a bit unrelated to the title of this question, I have asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348516/slidemenucontrollerswift-extra-white-space-issue-in-ios-11)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a background image for your navbar? Like this:

```
// Set Navigation bar background Image
let navBgImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "[image.jpg]")!
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBgImage, for: .default)
```

Comment: No I didn't try it, but thanks my problem is solved with the answer above.